# How to host iGoogle widgets in my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, google-widget

I am designing a dashboard for my own application to serve as a control panel for the end user. I am thinking about using the Dropthings framework or DynamicDashboards which cover all of my internal widgets requirements.

But besides including widgets developed internally by me, I would like for the user to be able to include iGoogle widgets as well.

Is this possible? 
What needs to be done in order to host an iGoogle widget?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody came forward and after some investigation I found that gadgets on iGoogle now support canvas view and OpenSocial, a common set of APIs, which means that I should find a way to support OpenSocial within ASP.NET.

There are porting projects for the OpenSocial API, although pretty inactive and incomplete.

So, as a final answer, it can be done but not easily.